# How to pass selected radio to controller in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I `console.log()` the selected radio? I also tried to have a selected default by adding `checked="checked"` but it didn't work.

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container"  ng-controller="radioController">
    <label for="redRadio">Red:</label>
    <input id="redRadio" type="radio" ng-model="colorValue" value="red" /><br />

    <label for="greenRadio">Green:</label>
    <input checked="checked" id="greenRadio" type="radio" ng-model="colorValue" value="green" /><br />

    <label for="blueRadio">Blue:</label>
    <input id="blueRadio" type="radio" ng-model="colorValue" value="blue" /><br />
    <br />
    <strong>Selected color:</strong> {{colorValue}}<br />

  </div>
<script>
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("radioController", function ($scope)
  {

   });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `ng-change` function on your radio button and pass the `ng-model` value as a parameter.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="radioController">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="red" ng-change="changedValue(color.name)">  Red <br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="green" ng-change="changedValue(color.name)"> Green <br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="blue" ng-change="changedValue(color.name)"> Blue <br/>
</div>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MW42bdv9GnsQWn2qLhEh?p=preview)

For reducing the html you could use `ng-repeat` directive that would render html for you, only you should maintain one array which will have various colors in it.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="color in colors">
  <input name="radio" type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="red" ng-change="changedValue(color.name)"> {{color.name}}
  <br/>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.colors = [{
  name: 'Green',
  value: 'green'
}, {
  name: 'Red',
  value: 'red'
}, {
  name: 'Blue',
  value: 'blue'
}];
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tsR08bus9TB67tkNVLGP?p=preview)

Comment: @downvoter please leave a comment to highlight what wrong?

Comment: Thanks Pankaj Parkar but can you please make a sample in plunker to see how it is working?

Comment: any way I removed the down vote from your question, not sure who did it?!

Comment: Thanks for update but this is not working  http://plnkr.co/edit/XasSYVVVC5dDjGtyZ0TO?p=preview

Comment: @MonaCoder look at the updated code..will let you once the `ng-repeat` version gets done

Comment: Thanks Pankaj , that will be great if you can also let me know how it works in ng-repeat version

Comment: @MonaCoder here is simple `ng-repeat` version with `ng-change` http://jsfiddle.net/vDTRp/416/

Comment: Thanks a lot  Pankaj,

Comment: @MonaCoder Glad to help you out..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
angular.module("app", [
]).controller("radioController", function ($scope, $log) {
   $scope.$watch('colorValue', function(colorValue){
       $log.info(colorValue);
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you need selected value in radio, just in controller initialize this value like $scope.colorValue = "blue" before watch, or you can use ng-init directive, and add near ng-controller in your html ng-init="colorValue = 'blue'"

Comment: Thanks Vladimir but this is not working http://plnkr.co/edit/MMKMy6sFyQUpYGM5Badb?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because it can be difficult for the original poster (or future readers) to understand the logic behind them. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Mona, But it works, you forgot to add <script src="script.js"></script> I've updated your plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/SLwmnrTDRl8jhbDQ6FF0?p=preview - generally in angular watchers usage are better, rather than ng-change function usage. Ng-change is better when we should ignore initial value.